# While using doodle from creativescala book I can't get my Image rotated by 180 degrees in recursive method

Tags: scala, graphics, 2d

I'm learning functional programming in Scala, and I can't get this done.

```
def lel2(bids: List[Double], vols: List[Double]): Image = {
  bids.size match {
    case 0 => Image.empty
    case n => Image.triangle(asks(n-1), vols(n-1))
      .transform(Transform.rotate(180.degrees)).above(lel2(bids.init, vols.init))
  }
}
```

The only dependecy is `"org.creativescala" %% "doodle" % "0.9.20"` and imports are `import doodle.core._; import doodle.image._; import doodle.image.syntax._; import doodle.image.syntax.core._; import doodle.java2d._`

What I'm trying to do is to output the rotated image of a triangle, flipped horizontally if that's the proper term :)

Also I use this `List[Double]`'s:

```
List[Double] = List(9.963005799312612, 9.964236205100441, 9.96497444857314, 9.972931072667766, 9.97317715382533, 9.979821345079607, 9.988352158541886, 10.0)

List[Double] = List(0.5617977528089887, 0.42134831460674155, 4.213483146067415, 0.5168539325842696, 0.5168539325842696, 2.6235955056179776, 2.1067415730337076, 10.0)
```

related links:

[Transform docs](https://github.com/creativescala/doodle/blob/4c0ff45958ea55543a435a3a545210bc8ecc0731/docs/src/main/mdoc/core/index.md)

[CreativeScala book](https://www.creativescala.org/)

[Doodle module](https://www.creativescala.org/doodle/index.html)

Comment: Please define what is not working, what are the inputs and what you expect as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put another parenthese around `Image.triangle(x, xx)` to tranform it like that

```
(Image.triangle(bids(n-1), vols(n-1))).transform(Transform.rotate(180.degrees))
```